# How to use MongoDB Subdocument _id with EJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to get a subdocument from MongoDB using Mongoose, then pass the data to an EJS doc but I'm getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` because of the `_id` object. Ideally I would like the `_id` to be a string, but using `toString()` or `toHexString()` doesn't work.

Here are my basic Schemas:

```
var hikeSessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hike_name: {type: String, required: true},
    hike_date: {type: String, required: true},
    mileage: {type: Number, required: true}
  })

var hikerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true},
  log: [hikeSessionSchema]
})

var HikeSession = mongoose.model('HikeSession', hikeSessionSchema)
var Hiker = mongoose.model('Hiker', hikerSchema)
```

And here's my `GET` request:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

...

app.get('/users/:id/:hike', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var hikeId = req.params.hike;

  Hiker.findById(id, (err, hiker) => {
    const hike = hiker.log.id(hikeId)

    console.log(hike)

    res.render('editHike', { data: hike })
  })
```

When I `console.log(hike)` I get:

```
{
  _id: 6125629447cec024c067c1da,
  hike_name: 'Hike Name',
  hike_date: '2021-08-04',
  mileage: 10
}
```

I've tried saving the `_id` to a variable as a string, then replacing the `_id` with the variable, but it goes back to an object. I've also tried `delete hike._id` but that doesn't work either.

I need to be able to be able to reference the `_id` in the EJS doc for later use. Maybe there's a way to get the `HikeSession` object without the `_id` and then save the `_id` separately? How can I make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround by duplicating the object without the `_id` field, making a variable for turning `_id` into a string, then adding that variable to the new object.

```
app.get('/users/:id/:hike', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var hikeId = req.params.hike;

  Hiker.findById(id, (err, hiker) => {
    var hikeData = hiker.log.id(hikeId)
    var hike = (({ hike_name, hike_date, mileage }) => ({ hike_name, hike_date, mileage }))(hikeData);

    var idStr = hikeData._id.toString()

    hike.id = idStr;

    res.render('editHike', { data: hike })
  })
```

Then importing in the EJS file like this:

```
var data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
```

There's probably a better way to do it, but this worked.